# How to Optimize Pool Settings GlassFish v3

Tags: optimization, jdbc, connection, glassfish-3, pool

I'm using GlassFish Server 3.2.1.1 and i'm trying to optimize  pool settings by changing default settings
I'm asking about how to estimate the maximum number of connections that can be created to satisfy client requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change from the administration console `localhost: 4848`
 from tab the tab Resources-->JDBC Resources---> Connection Pool:
 [image]